# Django template: change tags dynamically?

Tags: python, django, templates, macros

I would like to change some tags dynamically at Django template, for example:

```
{% autoescape on %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Here the autoescape is on, but I like to change to

```
{% autoescape off %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

by submitting a button value at user's side. How could I treat "on" and "off" as a variable here? (Does django template language has a mechanism like C's macro? )

Comment: FWIW, take a look at https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2511/ for an example of how to convert a built-in template tag to accept a variable for an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off autoescape temporarily, consider

```
{{ something | safe }}
```

where the `something` will not be escaped.